# Object with retain count 0 doesn't get released

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, reference-counting

Why is my object in the following leak trace doesn't get released?
[image]
The trace says its reference count is 0, so why doesn't it get released?
The object is a custom class that derives directly from `NSObject`. all I do with it is `alloc` it, `init` it, copy some strings/numbers from it, and send `release`, but still its considered a leak and doesn't get deallocated. I see it under allocations in instruments as 'living' so its really not deallocated. I create hundreds of these objects, so I cannot allow them to live.
How can I make this object get deallocated? why isn't it deallocated in the first place?

Comment: Just an observation/side-note : if your objects are truly just as temporary as you describe them to be, and you burn through hundreds to these — like cheap wrapping paper — it may get expensive to constantly alloc/dealloc them.  Maybe use a different design : flyweight design pattern, singleton design pattern, object pool, etc.

Comment: @QwertyBob: what the object basically does is take a file and parse it into a lot of strings/arrays/numbers. since there is many of them, I couldn't just return them, so I thought that making `initWithFilename:` populate properties on the object and later copy those properties off is a good idea. do you have a better one?

Comment: @QwertyBob: the problem that I'm facing tho isn't the time that its taking - it is not noticeable and the object number will not grow per unit of time (its kind of periodic), so the only problem I have its them being leaked.

Comment: @Dani, is QuickLevelLoader doing anything strange in -dealloc? Like forgetting to call [super dealloc], maybe?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer: thats it! forgot the `[super dealloc]` in custom `-dealloc`. can you post as answer?

Comment: @Dani: Allow me to suggest a custom snippet for `dealloc` that includes the `super` message. The snippet will never forget!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it looks like you forgot to call [super dealloc] in your -dealloc method. We've all done that. :)

So the object is getting the dealloc call as you would expect, but isn't actually being deallocated.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! After tearing my hair out I finally found this question and correct answer on stack overflow! Phew!